How to create a shortcut in plugin for a QKeySequence that is already used in QGIS?
Every time i try to call a shortcut in my QGIS plugin for a key sequence used in QGIS, QGIS action is called first. I need to use the same key sequence just for my action (method).

To disable QGIS shortcut (but not QGIS menu shortcut) for example Ctrl+n key sequence you can write:
man=QgsGui.shortcutsManager()
obj=man.objectForSequence(QKeySequence('Ctrl+n'))
if obj: obj.setEnabled(False)

Then you can use your QShortcut object without ambiguity.
